# how to test PageRank algorithm for jung?

Tags: java, algorithm, jung

I'm trying to test Pagerank algorithm for jung but it seems that I have a problem in doing it.
I have created a weighted and indirect graph with this portion of code:

```
private static String getId(int nodeId) 
    {
        return "Node " + nodeId;
    }

    private static String getId(int nodeId, int neighborId) 
    {
        return "Edge " + nodeId + " -> " + neighborId;
    }


public static Graph<String, Integer> createGraphForPageRank(String graphId, double[][] adjacencyMatrix) 
        {
         Graph<String,Integer> g = new UndirectedSparseGraph <String,Integer>();

            for (int nodeId = 0; nodeId < adjacencyMatrix.length; nodeId++)
                g.addVertex(getId(nodeId));



            for (int nodeId = 0; nodeId < adjacencyMatrix.length; nodeId++)
                for (int neighborId = 0; neighborId < adjacencyMatrix[nodeId].length; neighborId++)
                    if (adjacencyMatrix[nodeId][neighborId]>0)

                     g.addEdge(neighborId,getId(nodeId),getId(neighborId));



            return(g);

       }
```

then, in the main class, I used this code to test pagerank on my graph:

```
double[][] adjacencyMatrixForPageRank =FileHelper.calculateSimilaritySentences("E:\\my workspace\\TweetsAnalyser2\\outputFiles\\splittedStemmeredFile-1.txt","");
    Graph<String,Integer> g2=FileHelper.createGraphForPageRank("MyGraphForPageRank",adjacencyMatrixForPageRank);
    PageRank<String,Integer> pagerank= new PageRank<String,Integer>(g2,alpha1);
    pagerank.initialize(); 
    pagerank.setTolerance(0.000001);
    pagerank.setMaxIterations(200);
    pagerank.evaluate();
```

but eclipse generates this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: edge 4 already exists in this graph with endpoints  and cannot be added with endpoints 
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.AbstractGraph.getValidatedEndpoints(AbstractGraph.java:93)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.UndirectedSparseGraph.addEdge(UndirectedSparseGraph.java:64)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.AbstractGraph.addEdge(AbstractGraph.java:60)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.AbstractGraph.addEdge(AbstractGraph.java:55)
    at com.tweets.helpers.FileHelper.createGraphForPageRank(FileHelper.java:1496)
    at com.tweets.test.Main.main(Main.java:105)

I know that there is a problem with the graph creation, but I don't know how to solve it!!!!
Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be you defined an **undirected graph**, and you add the same node twice to it. One in the form of `(x,y)`, and one in the form of `(y,x)` - for the same values of `x` and `y`.

Solve it by iterating in your inner loop only from the `nodeID`, and not from 0:

```
for (int nodeId = 0; nodeId < adjacencyMatrix.length; nodeId++)
   for (int neighborId = nodeId; neighborId < adjacencyMatrix[nodeId].length; neighborId++)
                         ^^^
```

In addition:

```
g.addEdge(neighborId,getId(nodeId),getId(neighborId));
```

your edge ID is not unique, which I think it should be, but I am not familiar enough with the API to be sure.

Comment: Amira, in what way does the suggestion @amit provided not work?  He's put his finger on both problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems that led to your error.

(1) As @amit observed, since your graph is undirected, you don't need to add an edge from x to y and another one from y to x.
However, if you have the following code:

```
g.addEdge(edgeId, x, y);
...
g.addEdge(edgeId, y, x);
```

The second call to addEdge() will be silently ignored, which is fine.

(2) You can't reuse edge IDs for different sets of incident nodes; that's what that error message is telling you.  Edge objects (and node objects) are analogous to map keys: they have to be unique.

Your code suggests that you don't actually care about the edge objects per se, which means that you can just create a `Graph<String, Object>` and do this when you add an edge:

```
g.addEdge(new Object(), x, y);
```

This will get easier in JUNG in its next version, which I hope will be out in a few months.  :)

Comment: thanks @joshua, I understand that i have a problem with graph creation and especially with edges that my ID's are not unique, but I didn't understand how to deal with this problem considering your solution whenn you suggested to use "Object()".!!!

Comment: Edge IDs have to be unique.  You're reusing them: every time you have an edge that connects to vertex with index y in your matrix, you're using y as your edge id, which isn't unique and therefore won't work.  I've rephrased my answer a bit; does that help?

Comment: by the way, I was searching on how to create a jung graph from an adjacency matrix and I found this code:

Comment: Can I use it for creating my graph from an adjacency matrix then use Jung PageRank implementation?

Comment: You can do something like that, yes.  The essence of what that code is doing as far as you're concerned is that when an edge object is required, they're creating a new String by incrementing a variable every time a new edge is created and making a string out of the variable value.  That would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua for your time and your advice...hope that this code will solve my problem.

Comment: I'll try to implement something like that and will tell you if it works or not...but I suggest that is the solution for my problem.

Comment: The method matrixToGraph(DoubleMatrix2D, Factory<? extends Graph<V,E>>, Factory<V>, Factory<E>, Map<E,Number>) in the type GraphMatrixOperations is not applicable for the arguments (DoubleMatrix2D, Factory<UndirectedGraph<String,String>>, Factory<DirectedGraph<String,String>>, Factory<String>, Factory<String>, Map<String,Number>)